# Generate report of Hibernate vs DB inconsistencies

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to validate Hibernate against DB schema in a spring boot project, using  the property,

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

The project unfortunately never gotten validated, accumulating a huge number of inconsistencies. Going through the above method gives me only one inconsistency issue at time. I have to fix it to get the next inconsistency, which is time consuming and only one dev can work at a time.

Is there a way to get all the validation errors in single shot?. This would greatly help me and any answer is appreciated.